# Cleaning mixed type <script> tags

Tags: java, html-sanitizing, cyberneko

I'm cleaning HTML using cyberneko and xerces. 
However , some $#@@!@@ websites still use BOTH

```
<script>...</script> and <script.../>
```

So what happens is this : given

```
<script..../> <div> Some Text </div> <script> scripting stuff </script> ,
```

neko parses all the above line as a script , so I get

```
<script..../> &lt div &gt Some Text &lt/div &gt &lt script &gt scripting stuff </script> ,
```

And then I lose all the inside content :(

Any advice?

Comment: LOL , apparently the code parser of stackoverflow has the same problem :)

Comment: I'm amazed that anyone ever uses <script .../> (self-closed script tags) ever. It is so little trouble to output that closing tag, and the rewards are so great (complete compatibility), that you wonder where they think the win is for them in doing that?

Comment: @Robusto , I fully agree. The most annoying thing is the fact that these are major league content sites!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using <script /> is illegal in html. It is legal in xml. I don't know why some people still use the xml way to write html, but it's wrong, and it breaks most of the parsers (like SO..) - by design.

Another thing to notice - if you use xml parsers / dom4j parsers or any other thing that depends on it , make sure you're not passing your string through an xml parser and then an html parser - this will break everything.